# Lag in cell unhighlighting if I add a context menu button to it

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I noticed that when I add a context menu button to the cell, this causes a lag in unhighlighting the cell when pushing and popping back another view to the navigation stack.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(1..<5, id: \.self) { number in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, world!")) {
                    Text("\(number)")
                        .contextMenu { Button("") {} } // this line causes the lag.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Asperi Stackoverflow is not that site to comment on before you try - copy the code and run it then comment.

Comment: Confirmed on Xcode 13.2.1, iOS 15.2. I hate to call it a bug. It looks like an area where things could be a bit more streamlined. You can file a radar on it, they may get to it.